# Losing data between SOAP and JAX-WS

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, netbeans, jax-ws

I am having a problem with losing data when sending a java object from/to a web service over SOAP. We have a class called "User" which has a data member that is of another class which is called "Company". Both are defined to SOAP as complex types using java annotations for binding XML. For some reason when I try to send a User object to or from a web service It loses the data in the company member, showing the member as nothing but a null value. I have used the NetBeans debugger to determine that the company object is populated before it is sent and the NetBeans WS tester to show that SOAP is formatting the object properly. So it appears the problem is with Java's XML/SOAP to java translation.

Here is the SOAP response:

```
Method returned
```

com.lingosys.attask.ws.User : "com.lingosys.attask.ws.User@6f863b"
SOAP Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org

/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <S:Body>
            <ns2:getUser xmlns:ns2="http://ws.attask.lingosys.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.fault.lingosys.com">
                <UserID>85967</UserID>
            </ns2:getUser>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>

SOAP Response

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <S:Body>
            <ns2:getUserResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.attask.lingosys.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.fault.lingosys.com">
                <return>
                    <id>85967</id>
                    <name>Mohamed Abdullahi, Ph.D.</name>
                    <address>P.O. Box 56046</address>
                    <address2>407 Laurier Ave. W.</address2>
                    <adminNotes/>
                    <agreements xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <altPhone1/>
                    <altPhone2/>
                    <certifications/>
                    <city>Ottawa</city>
                    <company>
                        <id>7029</id>
                        <name>Mohamed Abdullahi, Ph.D.</name>
                        <addPMSurchargeforDocTrans>true</addPMSurchargeforDocTrans>
                        <checkKnowledgeMgt>false</checkKnowledgeMgt>
                        <clientID>0</clientID>
                        <docTransPricingScheme>LLS Pricing</docTransPricingScheme>
                        <greatPlainsID/>
                        <guid>c71d4c279af611e287980019d15adc73</guid>
                        <legalEntity>Lingo Systems</legalEntity>
                        <passTradosLeveraging>false</passTradosLeveraging>
                        <paymentTerms>0</paymentTerms>
                        <usLinguistsRequired>false</usLinguistsRequired>
                        <userDataID/>
                    </company>
                    <copyedit>0.0</copyedit>
                    <country/>
                    <email>annie@goodie.com</email>
                    <email2>mdiriye@hotmail.com</email2>
                    <fax/>
                    <firstName>Mohamed</firstName>
                    <helpFuzzy>0.0</helpFuzzy>
                    <helpNew>0.0</helpNew>
                    <helpReps>0.0</helpReps>
                    <hourly>0.0</hourly>
                    <lastName>Abdullahi, Ph.D.</lastName>
                    <lingoNetUser>false</lingoNetUser>
                    <linguistSource>Coto DB</linguistSource>
                    <llsClientID/>
                    <medicalFuzzy>0.0</medicalFuzzy>
                    <medicalNew>0.0</medicalNew>
                    <medicalReps>0.0</medicalReps>
                    <memberships xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <min>0.0</min>
                    <mktFuzzy>0.0</mktFuzzy>
                    <mktNew>0.0</mktNew>
                    <mktReps>0.0</mktReps>
                    <os/>
                    <pager/>
                    <phone/>
                    <pmComments/>
                    <postalCode>KIR 7Z0</postalCode>
                    <qualified xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <roles>Linguist Account</roles>
                    <rushFuzzy>0.0</rushFuzzy>
                    <rushNew>0.0</rushNew>
                    <rushReps>0.0</rushReps>
                    <sourceLanguage>English (US)</sourceLanguage>
                    <specialties xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <state>ON</state>
                    <targetLanguage/>
                    <taxID/>
                    <techFuzzy>0.0</techFuzzy>
                    <techNew>0.0</techNew>
                    <techReps>0.0</techReps>
                    <timeZone>US/Eastern</timeZone>
                    <title/>
                    <tools xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <trFuzzy>0.0</trFuzzy>
                    <trNew>0.0</trNew>
                    <trReps>0.0</trReps>
                    <translatorSince/>
                    <trceFuzzy>0.0</trceFuzzy>
                    <trceNew>0.0</trceNew>
                    <trceReps>0.0</trceReps>
                    <uiFuzzy>0.0</uiFuzzy>
                    <uiNew>0.0</uiNew>
                    <uiReps>0.0</uiReps>
                    <userName>mdiriye@hotmail.com</userName>
                </return>
            </ns2:getUserResponse>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

I have posted this problem on Java Ranch along with more code than can be included in this site's posts: http://www.coderanch.com/t/622496/Web-Services/java/losing-data-SOAP-Web-Service#2845835

Let me know if there is soem code or documents you might want to see. The funny thing is a very similar version of these Web Services and clients was working on a different environment. I'm in the process of upgrading form NB6.9 Glassfish v2, JDK 1.6 to NB7.3.1, GF4, JDK 1.7. A few code changes were made to the Company and User classes, but nothing that I would think could have anything to do with SOAP.

Any help would be apprecaited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted at coderanch: Your user and company-classes are not what I would call "jaxb marshalling friendly". :-) There is a whole bunch of logic in these "simple" transport objects. You might want to separate the business-logic and the transfer representation. But that's just a sidenote.

The bigger point is the exception your server threw when you annotated `private Company company;` with the `@XmlElement` annotation. The server started complaining about the "double" definition of an element. I would suggest you

**either** annotated the transfer objects (User & Company) with `@XmlAccessorType(NONE)`. That way you tell JAXB not to marshal any properties not explicitly defined to be marshaled. Than you annotate every property you *want* marshaled in the two classes with `@XmlElement` or `@XmlAttribute`.

**or** annotated the transfer object (User & Company) with `@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)`. That would coerce JAXB to build the XML output according to the fields defined in your class.

I would prefer the first option (in lieu of refactoring the whole class model to just include the data and no logic) since it makes clear which fields are marshaled to XML and which are not.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer sounds like it was the same thing I found and fixed just by changing the attribute name. I will try your solution when I get a chance. It would be great if that worked as well. One thing I was wondering about was your reference to the server throwing an exception. One of the things that made this problem so difficult was the fact that I didn't see exceptions of any kind. How did you get the server to throw an exception? I'm a little confused there. I agree with you about the the business logic not being in an appropriate place.

Comment: I used the @XmlAccessorType(FIELD) solution because it easily setup all the fields to go across which is how things were designed in the first place. Makes changing setters/getters in the client apps unnecessary. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The exception you posted on Coderanch: `Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "company"`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured out what is going on and thought I would share. Apparently, a bug crept in to JAX-WS or some related software so that if the name of an attribute is the same as the name of its class, it causes Java to have problems translating, even if the attribute begins with a lower case letter and the class name begins with an upper case letter. Once I changed the User class attribute Company object and its associated getters and setters from "company" to "userCompany" the problem went away. It looks like this bug crept in in the later stages of JDK 1.6. It wasn't a problem under our old environment with JDK 1.6.0_7, NB 6.9, and Glassfish V.2. However under the new NB 7.3.1 and GF4, there was a problem even when I set the JDK to 1.6.0_45 for the NetBeans default java platform.